# Sending a data from form while some of the inputs are not filled

Tags: node.js, forms, express

```
<form action="/test" method="post>
<input type="text" name="something">
<input type="text" name="something_again">
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

When I fill up both of the inputs, data is sent in req.body and I can use them as I want, but if I fill only one or no inputs, nothing is happening and req.body is empty. What can I do to have data in req.body when not all the inputs are filled?

Comment: *What can I do to make it work?* not very clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Provided some more info on what I need

Comment: you can set some default value in from like: `input type="text" name="something" value="default-value"`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar but what if this input is something like password and I can't just set it and make it visible?

Comment: What then? That's why I am looking for a solution

Comment: how are you rendering your html? is the form data sent from form directly using `submit`?

Comment: Yes, the button sends the data right to backend of the site